# Try Catch Should be used, except it never should?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

So I have been doing some research into how I should be doing try-catch-finally blocks and there is some conflicting information in every post I read.  Can someone clarify?

One common idea is to not catch exceptions that you do not know what to do with at that point in the code.  The exception will bubble up until it presumably gets to a global exception handler if nothing else catches it.  So at that point you display a message to the user that an unknown type of exception occurred, log it, etc.

Now after reading it sounds like this is the only exception handler that you will need?  You should not be using it for flow control, so you should be checking if something is returned as null or is invalid causing the exception and correcting it in code.  ie. testing for null and doing something about it before it can cause the exception.

But then there are other things such as running out of memory that you would not be able to test for, it would just occur during an operation and the exception would be thrown.  But I would not be able to do anything about this either so this would be bubbled up to the global handler.

I think there are some that I am missing, like when dealing with files there can be some thrown from the external code.  File not found exception seems like one that may come up often, so I would catch it and in the finally block gracefully close down anything I opened related to other code/processing and then notify the user and log it right there?

The only reason why you would want to catch an exception is for the finally part of the block to make sure that whatever you started before the exception is closed/finalized in a known state?  But even then you would want to throw this exception after performing these tasks so the user is notified by the global exception handler, there is no point duplicating this code at this point?

So other than a global exception handler you would have try-catch-finally blocks for these scenarios.

So assuming that I am missing something here, there may be the possibility that you want to try and catch a specific type of exception and then do something with it.  I cannot think of anything that you would want to do in the catch block though since the global one would log/notify the user and if you have an exception that usually means that there is no deal for the code to continue on.

Is there any easy way to know which exceptions will be thrown from which modules?  I think the only way I have read is to read the MSDN or component suppliers documentation, other than that there is no way to know what exception you would be trying to catch if you were looking for a specific one (not sure why you would)

This question came up since in my application I had a section of code in a try-catch block, and it ended up that when an exception occurred it was either because an object was null, or a string was invalid.  Once I wrote code to handle those scenarios the try-catch block is no longer needed, if an exception is encountered now there is nothing the code can do to recover so it should be logged and let the user know so it can be fixed.

But this goes against what I have been reading and what has been preached to me, bad code is code with no try-catch blocks.  So how does this all tie together and what piece am I missing here?

Comment: Reading [this great post](http://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) on Eric Lippert's blog might answer some of your questions.

Comment: An exception occurs when something unexpected happens. You should fix the unexpectedness. The reason people don't often use `try {} catch ()` is because it hides itself from unit testing. Having said that there are situations where you have no option (third-party libraries, int parsing?)

Comment: Nitpick: Not int parsing; use `TryParse` instead.

Comment: @CodyGray is correct, but it's the only example I could think of that an exception is pretty much *expected* :)

Comment: All good answers and information, wish there was a way to recognize that more than one answer contributed

Comment: There is, the upvote arrow. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your question is all correct: you should only catch exceptions that you know how to handle. Otherwise, just let them bubble up until they reach code that *can* handle them.

(Note that "handle" doesn't mean "log" or "display an error". It means to correct the problem that caused the exception, or work around it in some way.)

If they never encounter code that can handle them, or if they are unhandlable exceptions (like OutOfMemory), then they will eventually reach the *global unhandled exception handler*. This is where you will log the exception (if appropriate), display a generic error to the user (if appropriate), and more often than not, terminate the application. You cannot simply continue as if nothing happened—the exception indicates that the application is in an unexpected state. If you try and continue, you're just going to crash, or worse.

> I think there are some that I am missing, like when dealing with files there can be some thrown from the external code. File not found exception seems like one that may come up often, so I would catch it and in the finally block gracefully close down anything I opened related to other code/processing and then notify the user and log it right there?

FileNotFound is a good example of an exception that you will *want* to handle locally. In the same method (or perhaps one level up, in your UI code) that attempts to load the file, you'll have a `catch` block for FileNotFound exceptions. If appropriate, display a friendly error message to the user and ask them to choose another file. If it's internal code, give up and try something else. Whatever you need to do. There are few good reasons for FileNotFound to bubble up outside of your code.

This is *sort* of like using exceptions for flow control, but unavoidable. There is no way to avoid using exceptions (or error codes) for I/O, so you just need to handle the failure case. You *could* try and verify that the file exists *first*, before trying to open it, but that would not solve the race issue wherein the file gets deleted or becomes otherwise inaccessible between the time your verification code runs and when you actually try and open it. So now all you've done is duplicated your error-handling code in *two* places, which serves little purpose.

You *have* to handle exceptions like FileNotFound locally. The further away from the code that throws, the less likely you can do anything reasonable about it.

Another good example of this, aside from I/O-related exceptions, is a NotSupportedException. For example, if you try to call a method that isn't supported, you might get this exception. You will likely want to handle it and have code in the `catch` block that falls back to a safe alternative.

> The only reason why you would want to catch an exception is for the finally part of the block to make sure that whatever you started before the exception is closed/finalized in a known state? But even then you would want to throw this exception after performing these tasks so the user is notified by the global exception handler, there is no point duplicating this code at this point?

This does not require *catching* the exception. You can have a `try` block with only a `finally` block. A `catch` block is not required. In fact, this is *precisely* what `using` statement implements. If you have state that needs to be cleaned up in the event of an exception being thrown, you should implement the `IDisposable` pattern and wrap usage of that object in a `using` block.

> Is there any easy way to know which exceptions will be thrown from which modules? I think the only way I have read is to read the MSDN or component suppliers documentation, other than that there is no way to know what exception you would be trying to catch if you were looking for a specific one (not sure why you would)

Precisely. This is not really a problem, though, since you are only catching the exceptions that you can do something about. If you don't know that a module can throw a particular exception, you obviously can't have written code that can handle that exception.

The documentation will tell you all of the important exceptions that you might need to handle, like FileNotFound, SecurityException, or what have you.

> This question came up since in my application I had a section of code in a try-catch block, and it ended up that when an exception occurred it was either because an object was null, or a string was invalid. Once I wrote code to handle those scenarios the try-catch block is no longer needed, if an exception is encountered now there is nothing the code can do to recover so it should be logged and let the user know so it can be fixed.

Avoiding exceptions in the first place is always the best option. For example, if you can design your application so that a null object or invalid string is impossible, great. That is what we call robust code. In that case, you don't need to catch these exceptions because there's no way that you can handle it. You *thought* you already handled the problem, so if an exception is getting thrown anyway, it is a sign of a bug. Don't gloss over it with a `catch` block.

But sometimes, `catch` blocks are still necessary, and you write code *inside* of the `catch` block to handle the problem. In that case, there's probably no reason to re-throw the exception or log it, so you don't have any code duplication.

> But this goes against what I have been reading and what has been preached to me, bad code is code with no try-catch blocks. So how does this all tie together and what piece am I missing here?

Completely wrong. I don't know where you've been reading that, but it is nonsense. Exceptions are exceptional conditions. If your code has `catch` blocks strewn all over it, that is a sign that you are doing it wrong. Either you're using exceptions for flow control, you're swallowing exceptions in a misguided attempt to "improve reliability", or you don't know about the global unhandled exception handler.

Doesn't sound like you're missing anything to me.

The only thing I feel compelled to mention that doesn't fit strictly into any of your questions is that sometimes you might want to catch an exception and rethrow it as a *different* exception. The most common situation where you would do this is if you were designing a library of re-usable code. Inside of the library, you might catch internal exceptions and, if you cannot handle them, rethrow them as general exceptions. The whole point of a library is encapsulation, so you shouldn't let exceptions bubble up that the caller *cannot possibly do anything about*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *true* guide for exceptions management (raising and handling). Every app has to decide what level of flow control should be used and how exception has to be raised/handled.

General rules are:

- exceptions are raised in *exceptional* situations
- handle exception you *can* handle and do meaningful things for your app so
- exception raising *can* be used in flow control, actually it's the only way you can reliably handle flow control when you are dealing with devices, so hardware interrupts. (printers, bill validators, file transfer...)

The rest is up to you. The meaning of exception management is made by you.

Comment: You could also include the try-catch around database-related code; if the database fails, an exception will be raised and you will want to catch that and handle it off well.

Comment: One reason for exceptions is for programs that need to try very hard to survive and keep running. Another is for programs that need to try very hard to capture diagnostic info and then die.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you need to download some files from an FTP server, one you don't control. Of course you can't trust other people so you need to prepare for temporary outages and [such](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh851746.aspx/). So you wrap your downloading code in a `try-catch`-block and look for `WebException` if you catch one you might check for `FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailableOrBusy` if that was the error you simply retry. Similarly if you call a web service a `404` might be trouble, but a `429` means that you wait a little and retry, because you had been rate-limited.

Usually you can know which exceptions can be thrown by experience or documentation but C# lacks checked exceptions. Things like `NullPointerException` or `ArgumentNullException` can be properly handled with guards in your code. But other things, like errors external dependencies can sometimes be caught and handled by you without crashing the application.